# Текст пользователя в массив string

Tags: c#, массивы

Программа должна форматировать введенный пользователем текст.
Пример - Ввод: сссуууп, вывод - суп.
Я так понимаю проблема в том, что  `Console.ReadLine()` делает мне `char` массив, а как его преобразовать в `string` не понимаю.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Введите текст: ");
    string str = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] symbols = str.ToArray();
    var result = new List<string>();
    foreach (var element in text)
    {
        if (result.Count == 0 || result.ToString().Last() != element)
        {
            result.Add(element.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"{ result.ToString()}");
}
```

Выдает ошибку CS0029 - не удается неявно преобразовать тип char[] в string[]

В моменте сравнения
`result.ToString().Last() != element`
выдает ошибку CS0019 невозможно применить к оператору типа char и string.

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` - выдает строку, а строка по вашему это что? Правильно, это массив символов. Так что это `string[] symbols = str.ToArray();` вы можете смело выкидывать, ибо `string` и есть массив. Далее, вы перебираете символы, так почему у вас результатом является коллекция строк (`var result = new List<string>();`) ? Наверно это должна быть коллекция символов?

Comment: Преобразование из строки в массив символов нужно делать через метод `String.ToCharArray`, из массива символов в строку - через конструктор строки `String(char[] value)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Соглашусь с выше написанными комментариями. И кажется Вы не совсем понимаете, как работать со строками. Переменная `string str` уже является массивом символов и к нему можно обращаться через индексатор. Например: `str[0]` - возвращает первый символ строки. Почитайте больше информации по работе со строками, например на [metanit.com](http://metanit.com).
А по поводу решения вашей проблемы, если вам нужно удалять повторяющиеся символы из строки, то вот решение в одну строчку:

```
var result = new String(str.Distinct().ToArray());
```